# Printer spits out 'stair-cased' PostScript source code

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

I get this error when trying to print postscript created from a pdf using pdf2ps with ghostscript from a Kyocera 1370DN:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
              %%BoundingBox:  0  0  612  792
                                            %%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 905 (ps2write
```

- I checked to make sure the path was correct in the environment variables.
- I cleared the printer spooler data in : %WINDIR%\system32\spool\printers.
- I power cycled the printer and the pc that it was connected to.
- I checked and printed a test page. The test page works fine.
- It is the same error message every time.
- I printed some other documents from that printer and it prints fine.

Any advice?

Comment: so basically the pdf's raw bytes are being printed as text, and not "graphically"?

Comment: I'm not sure, there should be much, much much more there.

Comment: @MarcB: No, this is not *PDF* raw data -- it's PostScript source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method did you use to send your PostScript file to the printer?

It looks like your printer isn't a PostScript printer, and hence it doesn't understand PostScript code when it sees it.

You are sending PostScript code, and the printer only 'sees' text. So it prints the text....

The printer also doesn't see a CR/LF code at the end of the line, but only a LF code. Thats why you see this staircase effect.

Answer (score 2):

The printer supports PCL as well as PostScript, most likely it requires a (non-PostScript !) HP PJL sequence to tell the printer that the following is PostScript. Otherwise it will assume the data is PCL. PCL is a binary format, and when presented with 7-bit ASCII will treat it as text and print it, which is what appears to be happening here.

Try prepending the file with :

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL JOB
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=POSTSCRIPT
```

Note that  means the ESCAPE ASCII character code, ie 0x1B

And at the end of the file put:

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL EOJ
<ESC>%-12345X
```

Comment: Hehe... I was waiting for @dah to insist that the printer manual tells him PCL was supported before I would have advised him to switch the printer to PCL (can possibly also achieved by setting it up on the printer panel to 'auto-sensing' without a need to use `@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=...`).

Comment: What's the printer panel/auto-sensing.

Comment: @dah: Many printers allow to set them up in a way where they try to autodetect which language (PostScript or PCL) the job talks. **If** your printer supports this, then you do not need to prepend the `<ESC>%-12345.....=POSTSCRIPT` stuff (suggested by KenS) to your job. To do how KenS recommended is a safe way though...